# XML/XSLT conditional comment IE stylesheet

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt, cross-browser, conditional-comments, symphony-cms

I'm having an issue that I just can't seem to figure out. I built a website not too long ago in HTML and have recently integrated Symphony CMS and have had to change everything to XML.

Originally in my head, I had a internet explorer specific stylesheet, the head looked something like this:

```
<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen"></link>
       <!--[if IE]>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css"></link>
             <script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Since switching, this conditional comment does no longer work, I've changed it to this but unfortunately, my master.css is getting ignored for Chrome/Firefox etc... It is just loading the ie.css stylesheet for all browsers.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen"></link>                
    <xsl:comment>[if IE]<![CDATA[><!]]></xsl:comment>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css"></link>
          <script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <xsl:comment><![CDATA[<!]]>[endif]</xsl:comment>    
</head>
```

Sorry I'm fairly new at this and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm guessing I might need some sort of xsl:if comment but just not sure how to go about it really. I just need something that will make chrome/firefox/opera/safari ignore the ie.css stylesheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use one `xsl:comment` and wrap all of the contents in `<![CDATA[]]>`...

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen"></link>
        <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if IE 6]>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css"></link>
         <script src="../js/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
    </head>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I'll give this a try this evening and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd already tried the above but it appears it was my CDATA closing tag that was incorrect. You fixed my issue many thanks! :)

Comment: Accepted! Sorry I'm fairly new to this site :)

Comment: how to get a dynamic variable value inside a comment

Comment: Daniel's fix worked for me. One thing that tricked me up was that initially I had the <xsl:comment> on a separate line to <![CDATA[[if IE 6]>. When I did this the browser was unable to interpret the conditional comment, which confused me for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Use a template to allow conditional comments to be defined programmatically:

```
<xsl:template name="conditionalComment">
    <xsl:param name="qualifier" select="'IE'"/>
    <xsl:param name="contentRTF" select="''" />


    <!--Use entity variables to allow invalid XML output from an XSLT processor-->
    <xsl:comment>[if <xsl:value-of select="$qualifier"/>]<![CDATA[>]]>
    <!--Use copy-of rather than value-of to preserve tag delimiters-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$contentRTF" />
    <!--Use CDATA to output raw characters-->
        <![CDATA[<![endif]]]></xsl:comment>

</xsl:template>
```

The template takes two parameters:

```
<xsl:call-template name="conditionalComment">
    <!--Conditional check parameter-->
    <xsl:with-param name="qualifier" select="'lte IE 6'"/>
    <!--Stylesheet parameter-->
    <xsl:with-param name="contentRTF">
        &lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-win-fixup.css" /&gt;
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

**References**

- [IE Conditional Comments in XSLT 1.0](http://www.nickfitz.co.uk/2005/10/27/ie-conditional-comments-in-xslt-10/)
- [IE7-only stylesheet for XSL document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802830/1113772)
- [XSLT Utilities: IE Conditional Comments in XSLT](http://www.getsymphony.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/21798/)