# Leave comment symbols in the string during XSL transformation

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have the following code in my xsl file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lt IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
</script>
```

After transformation I'm getting empty `div.innerHTML`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "";
</script>
```

How to preserve `<!--[if lt IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->` in the output html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726792/xml-xslt-conditional-comment-ie-stylesheet). I had to use both `CDATA` and `<xsl:comment>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<xsl:comment><![CDATA[ [if lt IE 9]><i></i><![endif] ]]></xsl:comment>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try simply encoding the `<` characters along with a `<xsl:text>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "&lt;!--[if lt IE 9]><i></i>&lt;![endif]-->";
</xsl:text>
</script>
```

Or using a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
<![CDATA[
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lt IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
]]>
</xsl:text>
</script>
```

Or perhaps you could even use a `<xsl:comment>` node, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<xsl:comment><xsl:call-template name="iecc"/></xsl:comment>";
</script>

<xsl:template name="iecc">[if lt IE 9]>&lt;i>&lt;/i>&lt;![endif]</xsl:template>
```

Comment: CDATA ends in `div.innerHTML = "&lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;`

Comment: <xsl:comment> node gives `div.innerHTML = "<!---->";`

Comment: @Ask See my updated answer. I've verified each solution using http://xslttest.appspot.com/